# jquery 1.9.2 dialog auto resize

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am having a problem in making my jquery dialog to automatically resize to content, I am using jquery ui 1.9.2 and I am using the following settings:

```
{
autoResize: true
close: function (e, ui){
height: "auto"
maxHeight: 600
maxWidth: 800
minHeight: 300
minWidth: 400
modal: true
width: "auto"
}
```

and the resulting behavior is: http://screencast.com/t/1OwLgVHDH
so it only resizes correctly after I manually drag the resize handler,

do I need to manually trigger a resize (I tried this but I don't know how to, I tried .trigger('resize') and i tried trigger('resizeStart') didnt work)?

and I have tried to use the auto width as seen on the object I pass into the dialog function, didn't work either.

Please help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the order of specifying the sizing options changes the behavior significantly.

For example, I wanted to use the same dialog box for two different input styles, a wide one for a text input and a narrower one for an image input, but I could only get it to work right like this:

```
            "autoResize": true,
            "autoOpen":false,
            "modal":true,
            "width": "auto",
            "height": "auto",
             -->"resizable":false
```

Whereas this came out with unexpected problems:

```
            "autoResize": true,
            "autoOpen":false,
            "modal":true,
             -->"resizable":false,
            "width": "auto",
            "height": "auto"
```

I would try moving your '"height":"auto"' down to the last line with your "width" setting.